# Xamarin:Android - Layout_Height changes with wordwrap

Tags: android, layout, xamarin.android, height, android-linearlayout

I have three identical buttons in one linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Kamera öffnen" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Bild hochladen" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Abbrechen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I turn my device from horizontal to vertical, the text of the first two buttons need a wordwrap. 
The problem is, that the buttons change their height -> the two buttons with wordwrap have a lower height than the third button with only one text line.

Horizontal view:
[image]

Vertical view:
[image]

Why is that happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this following xml will resolve your problems.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:weightSum="3">
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Kamera öffnen" />
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Bild hochladen" />
<Button
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_clear"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Abbrechen" />
```

Use weightSum on root layout while your are using layout_weight coz it will make conflict when you have more view or complex view. You should also use layout_width/height="0dp" depending on root layout orientation for getting the advantage of layout_weight. Because you trying to control your view using weight. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not solve the problem